# The Hasse Minkowski theorem in Peano arithmetic

Tags: nt.number-theory, proof-theory

Harvey Friedman's "Concrete Mathematical Incompleteness" at http://www.math.osu.edu/~friedman.8/pdf/0.Intro061311.pdf  cites the Hasse Minkowski theorem saying quadratic forms over a number field are equivalent if and only if they are equivalent over every completion of the field (real, complex, or $p$-adic).  He says "It would appear that using standard techniques, this can be put into" first order arithmetic.  He asks whether it or some stronger theorem can be made $\Pi^0_2$ or even $\Pi^0_1$.

Is there published work on this problem?

Comment: The standard methods he mentions are standard in practice.  The usual proofs of Hasse-Minkowski over $\mathbb{Q}$ (the case for other number fields is similar) reduce the $p$-adic calculation for any given rational quadratic form to calculations mod $p^n$ for $n$ specifiable from the coefficients of the form.  And that is the usual point of using the theorem.  But has anyone gone into the specific quantifier complexity of the theorem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The community has spoken by silence.  No one has worked on this.

Comment: To allude to a standard joke about mathematicians: you know that there is at least one sheep one side of which is black.  A deduction about all the sheep in Scotland may be unwarranted.

Comment: This community is not sheep.